# SQL query returning data, but not populating within code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tblUser_GetAllInfo]
    @Email NCHAR(25),
    @UserID INT
AS
    SELECT 
        tblUser.Firstname, tblUser.Lastname, tblPersonal.Age, tblPersonal.Sex
    FROM 
        tblUser, tblPersonal
    WHERE 
        tblUser.UserID = @UserID AND tblPersonal.UserID = @UserID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        SELECT Firstname, Lastname
        FROM tblUser
        WHERE UserID = @UserID

    RETURN @@IDENTITY
```

This stored procedure is run within the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //copy email from query string
        Email = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Email"]);
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome to Love Finder, " + Email;
        UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["UserID"]);

        //add params
        db.AddParameter("Email", Email);
        db.AddParameter("UserID", UserID);

        //execute GetAllInfo query
        db.Execute("sproc_tblUser_GetAllInfo");

        //if entries in both tables found, do this
        if (db.Count == 1)
        {
            //get parameters
            User.ThisID.Firstname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Firstname"]);
            User.ThisID.Lastname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Lastname"]);
            User.ThisID.Sex = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Sex"]);
            User.ThisID.Age = Convert.ToInt32(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Age"]);

            //send to text boxes
            txtName.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Firstname + "" + User.ThisID.Lastname);
            txtAge.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Age);
            txtSex.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Sex);
        }
        else 
        {
            //if only one table entry found (User), do this
            User.ThisID.Firstname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Firstname"]);
            User.ThisID.Lastname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Lastname"]);

            txtName.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Firstname + "" + User.ThisID.Lastname);
        }
    }
```

The query relies on there being columns in both the `User` and `Personal` table. If I run the application with a member who has entered columns into both tables, it returns what I want it to. However, for the sub query that only collects data from the `User` table, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no row at position 0.

TLDR:

When I execute the query by itself by giving it the parameters its being passed by the query string, it works and returns what it should. But, when run through the code, I'm getting the above error.

Can anyone shed light on this? It's probably something glaringly obvious, but I'm quite new to C# programming.

Kind regards

Comment: Huh?  `@@Identity` should be used with `SELECT INTO` or `INSERT`.  It is not appropriate for a mere `SELECT`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what is `db` here? because it isn't raw ADO.NET

Comment: if `db.Count` is 0, then we would expect `Rows[0]` to throw an indexoutofrange

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a `left join`?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tblUser_GetAllInfo] (
    @Email NVARCHAR(255),
    @UserID Int 
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT u.Firstname, u.Lastname, p.Age, p.Sex
    FROM tblUser u LEFT JOIN
         tblPersonal p
         ON p.UserID = u.UserId
    WHERE u.UserID = @UserID ;
END;
```

This will always return four columns.  The ones from `tblPersonal` will be `NULL` if no match is found.

Your problem is that your stored procedure sometimes returns two columns and sometimes returns four columns.  Then, C# has a problem parsing the result set.

Notes:

- If you are going to be using a result set, use a table-function instead of a stored procedure.  That is the appropriate thing to use.
- Don't use commas in the `from` clause.  Use proper, correct `join` syntax.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- `@@IDENTITY` is not appropriate for `SELECT` statements.
- `NCHAR(25)` is not appropriate for an email address.  First, 25 characters might not be sufficient.  Second, `NCHAR()` pads the address with spaces, and those are not appropriate.

Comment: This worked perfectly after I swapped out the IF in the C# with a try catch. Thanks a ton.

Thanks for the notes as well. Will take those on board!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just make what you currently have *work*, just change your stored proc from this:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname
FROM tblUser
WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

to this:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Age='', Sex=''
FROM tblUser
WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

You always need to return the same number of columns.

Comment: I went with a prior solution, but I will keep this in mind! Thank you.

Comment: No problem!  The chosen solution is definitely a better way of solving your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`return @@identity`? any ways...I will modify your stored procedure as..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tblUser_GetAllInfo](
    @Email NCHAR (25),
    @UserID Int
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT tblUser.Firstname, tblUser.Lastname, tblPersonal.Age, tblPersonal.Sex
    FROM tblUser
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPersonal
    ON   tblUser.UserID = tblPersonal.UserID
    WHERE tblUser.UserID = @UserID
RETURN 0
END
```

and .net code `if` condition as, get rid of `else`

```
if (db.Count >= 1)
{
    //get parameters
    User.ThisID.Firstname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Firstname"]);
    User.ThisID.Lastname = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Lastname"]);

//send to text boxes
txtName.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", User.ThisID.Firstname, User.ThisID.Lastname);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Sex"]))
{
    User.ThisID.Sex = Convert.ToString(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Sex"]);
    txtSex.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Sex);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Age"]))
{
    User.ThisID.Age = Convert.ToInt32(db.DataTable.Rows[0]["Age"]);
    txtAge.Text = Convert.ToString(User.ThisID.Age);
}
}
```